# RegEx for preg_match_all not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

This is my string (`$string`):

```
    swatch: 'http://abc.com/aa.jpg',
    zoom:[
      'http://abc.com/bb.jpg'
    ],
    large:[

      'http://abc.com/cc.jpg'
    ],
```

I use the following pattern in my PHP file and want to match `http://abc.com/bb.jpg`:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=zoom:\[\s{15}\').*(?=\')/', $string, $image);
```

But nothing is returned. What should I do?

Comment: funny, you actually counted the number of spaces ? Use `\s*` and add the `s` modifier to match new lines :) Also if this is JSON use `json_decode()` instead.

Comment: Ah my bad, you can't use quantifiers in lookaround in PHP ...

Comment: You can't use quantifiers in any lookaround engine, as far as I know. I agree on using `json_decode()` instead of regex for this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it simpler, we won't use look around and although I said that we need the `s` modifier, I was wrong it's only used to match new lines with dots `.` which we won't be using here, so `\s` matches a new line:

```
$string = <<<JSO
        swatch: 'http://abc.com/aa.jpg',
        zoom:[
          'http://abc.com/bb.jpg'
        ],
        large:[

          'http://abc.com/cc.jpg'
        ],
JSO;
preg_match_all('/zoom:\[\s*\'(?<img>[^\']*)\'\s*\]/', $string, $m);
print_r($m['img']);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://abc.com/bb.jpg
)
```

**Explanation:**

```
/ # Starting delimiter
    zoom:\[ # Matches zoom:[
    \s* # Matches spaces, newlines, tabs 0 or more times
    \'  # Matches '
    (?<img>[^\']*) # named group, matches everything until ' found
    \'  # Matches '
    \s* # Matches spaces, newlines, tabs 0 or more times
    \]  # Matches ]
/ # Ending delimiter
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of 's' at the end?

Comment: @user1610115 Do you mean `\s*` ? This will match spaces, newlines, tabs 0 or more times. Otherwise there is the `s` modifier which is used to match newlines with a dot `.`.